# castle: register interface proxies by convention

Tags: castle

I want to register multiple components implementing the dictionary adapter, but the AllTypes.From.. only picks class-types. I want to do something like this:

```
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IFooSettings>()
            .Where(type => type.IsInterface)
            .Configure(component =>
                component.UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, model, creationContext) => new DictionaryAdapterFactory().GetAdapter(creationContext.RequestedType, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings))));
```

Now I can't seem to be able to create my own version of "AllTypes" since the FromTypesDescriptor ctor is internal. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now works in Castle 3.3.0:

```
var dictionaryAdapterFactory = new DictionaryAdapterFactory();

container.Register(
        Types.FromThisAssembly().Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Settings") && t.IsInterface)
            .Configure(component => component.UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, model, creationContext) => dictionaryAdapterFactory.GetAdapter(creationContext.RequestedType, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings))));
```

You have to use "Types" which also picks up interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this

```
    container.Register(
        AllTypes
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick()
            .WithService.DefaultInterface()
            .Configure(r => r.LifeStyle.Transient));
```

This registers components based on a matching interface and class name.

So if I ask Castle for an interface called `IFooSettings` then Castle will by default return the class `FooSettings`.

There are a series of rules you can use for registration and you can see them [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-one-by-one&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). It's does not recommend using the Factory method you are using in your example.

Comment: You are not answering the question. Read the title, I want to register types which Castle automatically creates proxies for. Read up on the DictionaryAdapter.